# cellForRowAtIndexPath not executing for all Custom View Cells from NIB file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm having an issue with running two `TableView`s in the one `ViewController`.

**EDIT:**
To make the question a bit more understandable, I've placed the snippet below of the code.

**Things that may be relevant:**

1. Both use custom cells.
2. From what I have done with the debugger, it looks at though it doesn't pass through the following if statement:

   if (tableView == self.tblFriendsList){...}

3.Initially I was trying to use a Containment View to add the second UITableViewController, but now I have opted to try using a UITableView.

4. The containment view (which includes the two tableViews) comes from a NIB.
5. I have tried both adding the delegate and datasource manually, and through the file's owner.
6. I have changed the code so that if it doesn't execute the if statement, then it will execute what is required for the other table (which is setting up successfully), but previously it was also working for the first table when I used the example that I have written below. It is the other table that fails to load when both when used as a tableView or when I try adding an entire ViewController to a subview (I've been interchanging between both to try to solve this).
7. Spelling has been checked on the actual code many-a-time, so I'm more thinking that it may have to do with the fact that it isn't entering the if statement for the one mentioned above.
8. Most examples I have seen from videos/Stack Exchange have mainly been prior to this year, so I am wondering if there has been an update to practical coding that I have missed.
9. Sadly I am only doing this for a job for someone wanting an exact replica of their design, or I would have thought of a nicer alternative!
10. I have attempted all answers so far, but have come up short... although I have seen too many tutorials on this that have succeeded, so I am very unsure about something funny going on...

**EDIT AGAIN 11.** Even when setting the tableView tag and running an if statement, the debugger still shows the code skipping past the if statement. Even when the **reload data** method is called, the debugger does not have another break when it should.

Currently, the code sits as this:

**For viewDidLoad:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.m_arrVenueList=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.m_dictCells = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [self setNavigationProperties];
    [self loadFriendByLocation];
    [self setRefreshController];
    self.m_dictFriendListCells = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    self.tblFriendLocation.delegate = self;
    self.tblFriendLocation.dataSource = self;

    self.tblFriendsList.delegate = self;
    self.tblFriendsList.dataSource = self;
    [self.tblFriendsList reloadData];
}
```

**For numberOfRowsInSection:**

**Note: Just one section for each.**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if (tableView == self.tblFriendsList) {
    return [self.arrFriendsList count];
}
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.m_arrVenueList count];
}
```

**For cellForRowAtIndexPath:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (tableView == self.tblFriendsList) {
  NSDictionary *friends=[self.arrFriendsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  NSString *friendID = [Utility formattedValue:[friends objectForKey:@"user_id"]];

  // Configure the cell using friend object...
  NSString *sIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TableCell_%ld",(long)friendID];

  FriendListVenueCell *cell = (FriendListVenueCell *)[self.m_dictCells objectForKey:sIdentifier];
  cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

  if (cell == nil)
  {
    cell = (FriendListVenueCell*)[Utility getViewFromXib: @"FriendListVenueCell" classname:[FriendListVenueCell class] owner:tableView];
    if (indexPath.row%2 != 0)
    {
      cell.contentView.backgroundColor =  UIColorWithRGB(11,21,39);
    }
    else
    {
      cell.contentView.backgroundColor =  UIColorWithRGB(12,23,32);
    }
  }
  [cell setCellDataForFriend:friends];
  [self.m_dictCells setObject:cell forKey:sIdentifier];

  return cell;
}

// Configure the cell using friend object...
NSString *sIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TableCell_%ld",(long)indexPath.row];
FriendsAtVenueCell *cell = (FriendsAtVenueCell*)[self.m_dictCells objectForKey:sIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = (FriendsAtVenueCell *)[Utility getViewFromXib:@"FriendsAtVenueCell" classname:[FriendsAtVenueCell class] owner:tableView];
    cell.m_FriendViewContrller = self;
    [self.m_dictCells setObject:cell forKey:sIdentifier];
    if (indexPath.row%2 != 0)
    {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor =  UIColorWithRGB(11,21,39);
    }
    else
    {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor =  UIColorWithRGB(12,23,32);
    }
}
cell.delegate=self;
Venue *tempDic=(Venue*)[self.m_arrVenueList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell setCellData:tempDic];

if (tempDic.nVenueId == 0)
{
    [cell.m_imgLogo setHidden:YES];
    [cell.m_imgLogobg setHidden:YES];
    [cell.m_btnFollow setHidden:YES];

}
cell.btnFifthImg.tag = indexPath.row;
cell.m_btnFollow.tag = tempDic.nVenueId;
cell.m_RowId= indexPath.row;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
return cell;
```

}

So far, what I have attempted to do - from what I have read from StackExchange and seen on tutorials - is to have the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` have separate cases for each `cell` and then return that `cell`.

Examples include

```
if (tableView == oneTableViewOutlet) { 
    //load cell
    return cell;
} else if (tableView == anotherTableViewOutlet) {
    //load cell
    return cell;
}
```

Hopefully this hasn't made the question too long, I am trying to condense it!

**EDIT FINISHED**

I've watched it with success on a few videos where they have added the `delegate` and `datasource` to self for each respective `TableView` outlet and it has worked from there, but I am having the issue of one outlet loading and not the other.

The above image has me debugging the issue, where I have Stepped Through the execution of the function and it has successfully initiated the first case, but then returns from the function and does not execute for the other TableView.

The code is tricky as I have custom cases in it, but if there are any other thoughts on debugs or references to help that would be appreciated.

In summary:

2 `TableViews`
Both hooked up to `delegate` and `datasource`
2 Custom `NIB` Cells used for each `table`
Only one executing

Comment: Update your question with the relevant code. Don't post a link. Show your `numberOfSections`, `numberOfRowsInSection`, and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` methods. Copy and paste the actual methods into your question.

Comment: u want to display both tableview value?

Comment: try to set delegate and datasource programmatically just before reloading table. There is only something very minor that you are missing.

Comment: Note: it's `else if`, not `else is`

Comment: Apologies @AlejandroIván - that was just a typo on here!

Comment: @rmaddy sorry! I was trying to condense it as best I can without taking too much time off everyone :( posted up the code. Do not currently have numberOfSections as just 1 is default/required for each table.

Comment: @MilanGupta tried but still no win! I am suspicious about this one... something small does seems off given every source code snippet/video/tutorial I have checked against.

Comment: This may be a long shot, but... where are you loading the data for your arrays? I mean... in `viewDidLoad` you have `[self loadFriendByLocation];` but how does that `loadFriendByLocation` method work? Is it asynchronous? If so, are you calling `reloadData` when the actual data is completely fetched?

Answer (score 0):

Add 
`NSLog(@"Table:%@", tableView)` at Line 204.
See if it prints two different tableViews.
and Try replacing Line 205 with `if([tableView isEqual:self.tblFriendLocation])`

Comment: Do not use `isEqual:` to check which table it is. Use `==`.

Comment: Good thinking on the NSLog! It has only shown up once... Which was also my thought about using the debugger. Now that confirms it. The only thing that I haven't been able to cross reference a lot with it the fact that they are using custom cells, although I can't see that being an issue if the table is not entering the "if" statement

Answer (score 0):

Set the tag for your tableview and compare with tag

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


        TablevIewCell1 *cell1=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellId1"];
        TablevIewCell2 *cell2=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellId2"];


        switch (tableView.tag) {
            case 1:
                [cell1.textLabel1 setText:[self.arrForTableView1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
                return cell1;

                break;

            case 2:
                [cell2.textLabel2 setText:[self.arrForTableView2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
                return cell2;

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return nil;
    }
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (tableView ==self.tableView1)
        return self.arrForTableView1.count;
    else
        return self.arrForTableView2.count;
    }
```

or else

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    TablevIewCell1 *cell1=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellId1"];
    TablevIewCell2 *cell2=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellId2"];

    if ([tableView isEqual:self.tableView1]) {
        [cell1.textLabel1 setText:[self.arrForTableView1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        return cell1;

    } if ([tableView isEqual:self.tableView2]){
        [cell2.textLabel2 setText:[self.arrForTableView2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        return cell2;

    }


    return nil;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This is not failsafe, you should use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` which ensures you won't get `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if([tableview isEqual:tblName])
```

First of all this is how you must check equality. Secondly post all methods so that one can see exactly what is wrong with your code.